# How to see when/why redis get slow/swamped?

Tags: redis, newrelic

We run Redis 2.8 on CentOS

Works great!

It appears that at times, our Redis server gets swamped and slow to respond. But we do not yet have data to really see whatwhen this happens.

What monitoring options do we have?

We use New Relic, but its redis agent appears unsupported/outdated (we have not been able to make it work, and New Relic support is unresponsive).  How, can we get closer to the issue, via New Relic or other tool?

Answer (score 0):

The Redis command [SLOWLOG](http://redis.io/commands/slowlog) displays a list a the slow requests.

By example SLOWLOG GET 10 returns the ten last entries from the logs of slow requests.

Comment: Is there a monitoring app/console that integrates w SLOWLOG to give us visibility and logging to this aspect?